# How can I get htlatex to work with amsmath's align and cleveref?

Tags: amsmath, align, cleveref, htlatex

I have a document `test.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtEndPreamble{\usepackage{cleveref}}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
.
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

It compiles fine under `latex` and `pdflatex`.  However, when I run it with `htlatex`, I get

```
D:\Documents\GitHub\book>htlatex test.tex   
D:\Documents\GitHub\book>latex  \makeatletter\def\HCode{\futurelet\HCode\HChar}\def\HChar{\ifx"\HCode\def\HCode"##1"{\Link##1}\expandafter\HCode\else\expandafter\Link\fi}\def\Link#1.a.b.c.{\g@addto@macro\@documentclasshook{\RequirePackage[#1,html]{tex4ht}}\let\HCode\documentstyle\def\documentstyle{\let\documentstyle\HCode\expandafter\def\csname tex4ht\endcsname{#1,html}\def\HCode####1{\documentstyle[tex4ht,}\@ifnextchar[{\HCode}{\documentstyle[tex4ht]}}}\makeatother\HCode .a.b.c.\input  test.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic, 
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, german-x-2012-05-30, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, latin, latvian,
 lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerman, n
german-x-2012-05-30, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, roman
ian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swissgerm
an, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, usengl
ishmax, welsh, loaded.
(D:\Documents\GitHub\book\test.tex
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"))
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\tex4ht.sty")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\usepackage.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsmath.sty"
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amstext.sty"
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsgen.sty"))
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsbsy.sty")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsopn.sty"))
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\etoolbox\etoolbox.sty"
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\misc\etex.sty"))
(D:\Documents\GitHub\book\cleveref.sty)
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\tex4ht.4ht"
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
 TeX4ht info is available in the log file 
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
) ("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\tex4ht.sty"
--- needs --- tex4ht test ---
(D:\Documents\GitHub\book\test.tmp) (D:\Documents\GitHub\book\test.xref)
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\latex.4ht"
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht"))
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\fontmath.4ht"
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht"))
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\article.4ht"
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht"))
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\amsmath.4ht"
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht"))
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\amstext.4ht"
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht"))
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\amsbsy.4ht"
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht"))
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\amsopn.4ht"
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht"))
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("D:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht"))
(D:\Documents\GitHub\book\test.aux)
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.8 \end{align}

? 
! Emergency stop.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.8 \end{align}

No pages of output.
Transcript written on test.log.
Terminate batch job (Y/N)?
```

Comment: it compiles without error for me, with TL 2013

Comment: What version of cleveref, amsmath, and tex4ht/htlatex do you have?

Comment: cleveref 0.19, dated 2013/12/28, amsmath 2.0, tex4ht doesn't seem to have version number (or I can't find it)

Comment: Turns out the problem was that I was using 2011/03/22 v0.17.9 of cleveref.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some help from the comments, the problem was that I was using version 2011/03/22 v0.17.9  of cleveref, and needed to update; 0.19, dated 2013/12/28 was sufficient.